# lmtest/lrtest throws data.frame error when data passed through rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have an error that occurs only when I call lrtest (from the lmtest package) from a user-defined function via rpy2.

R:

```
continuous.test <- function(dat) {
  require('lmtest')
  options(warn=-1)
  model <- lm(formula='pheno ~ .', data=dat)
  anova <- lrtest(model,'interaction')
  pval  <- anova$"Pr(>Chisq)"[2]
}
```

When I call this function from the R interpreter, everything runs correctly. However, I receive an error when calling from the following snippet of python code. Note, this particular python file makes many other calls to rpy2 with success.

Python:

```
...
kway_dat = R.DataFrame(dataframe) # this is a valid dataframe, it's used in other calls.
...
R.r("source('/path/to/user/defined/file/perm_test.r')")
continuous_test = R.r['continuous.test']
pval = continuous_test(kway_dat)
```

Error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dat' not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_r_.py", line 83, in <module>
    pval = continuous_test(kway_dat)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.6dev_20120806-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.6dev_20120806-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 34, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dat' not found
```

Troubleshooting:

- I have tested the code in R and everything works fine.
- I have passed a dataframe from python to R through rpy2 and called is.data.frame(dat) from an R function, and it returns true, so the issue is with lmtest or lrtest + rpy2.

Any help would be great. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to help with a self-contained example (so one can reproduce exactly what you are experiencing).

A possible answer still: you might want to check that the content of the file
`/path/to/user/defined/file/perm_test.r` is really what you think it is.

I am also adding a stub for a self-contained example:

```
r_code = """
  require('lmtest')
  options(warn=-1)
  continuous.test <- function(dat) {
    model <- lm(formula='pheno ~ .', data=dat)
    anova <- lmtest::lrtest(model,'interaction')
    pval  <- anova$"Pr(>Chisq)"[2]
  }
"""

from rpy2.robjects import packages
my_r_pack = packages.SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(r_code, "my_r_pack")

# [build a demo kway_dat here]

my_r_pack.continuous_test(kway_dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Found**

The issue was lrtest's internal call to update the model. Once inside lrtest, dat was out of scope. By updating the model manually and using lrtest's alternative call lrtest(model0,model1), the issue is entirely avoided.

Thanks to Achim Zeileis who replied incredibly promptly.